# What's the difference between Visual Studio Community and other, paid versions?

Tags: visual-studio

What's missing in Visual Studio Community 2015? They say it's full-featured and *free*, but if that's the case, then why do/will they still sell Visual Studio Ultimate 2015 or Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 for 6 grand?

Something is missing in the Community preview, right? And why is it called 'Community'? My code won't be synced across your devices like the new Windows 10 update system is, will it? (Kind of joking about that last part, and kind of not, too).

Comment: For a detailed comparison, this may be useful: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Check the following: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/
Visual studio community is free version for students and other academics, individual developers, open-source projects, and small non-enterprise teams (see "Usage" section at bottom of linked page).  While VSUltimate is for companies. You also get more things with paid versions!

Comment: Yeah. I assumed so. But then technically it isn't full featured. I'd be more inclined to say it's probably ~85% featured. I did see that page, however I fail to see where they compare Community to the others, unless it's called something else on that page.

Comment: @SE505: *Q: How does Visual Studio Community 2013 compare to other Visual Studio editions?
A: Visual Studio Community 2013 includes **all the great functionality of Visual Studio Professional 2013**, designed and optimized for individual developers, students, open source contributors, and small teams.* (see: https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs)

Comment: For anyone else who's curious as to the specific differences between Community and Professional, there are two big ones: Community has (1) no Team Foundation Server features, and (2) does not support [CodeLens](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/54b2682c-47f4-48ee-9d6d-190402330c49).

Comment: Link for Visual Studio 2015 editions... https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs

Comment: Exactly @theftprevention, those are my two concerns about the Community Edition

Comment: For VS 2015, Community and Professional are functionally virtually identical.  The major areas of difference are: 1) No free training materials (access to PluralSight, Azure etc) with Community, and 2) No support for Microsoft's Team Foundation server (collaborative/team development tools).  It provides everything needed for professional development as an individual and for many small teams.

Comment: @theftprevention, are there any free alternatives for CodeLens ?

Comment: ***VS 2017*** not supports ***TFS*** ?

Comment: OK the "non-enterprise" clause here is FALSE.  Microsoft has clarified that Community is for ANY USE as long as your revenue is under $1 Million US dollars.  That is literally the only difference between Pro and Community.  Open source doesn't matter, corporate or free or not, irrelevant.

Answer (score 265):

There are 2 major differences.

1. Technical
2. Licensing

Technical, there are 3 major differences:

First and foremost, Community doesn't have TFS support. 
You'll just have to use git (arguable whether this constitutes a disadvantage or whether this actually is a good thing). 
***Note:*** This is what MS wrote. Actually, you can check-in&out with TFS as normal, if you have a TFS server in the network. You just cannot use Visual Studio **as** TFS **SERVER**.

Second, VS Community is severely limited in its testing capability. 
Only unit tests. No Performance tests, no load tests, no performance profiling.

Third, VS Community's ability to create Virtual Environments has been severely cut.

On the other hand, syntax highlighting, IntelliSense, Step-Through debugging, GoTo-Definition, Git-Integration and Build/Publish are really all the features I need, and I guess that applies to a lot of developers.

For all other things, there are tools that do the same job faster, better and cheaper.

If you, like me, anyway use git, do unit testing with NUnit, and use Java-Tools to do Load-Testing on Linux plus TeamCity for CI, VS Community is more than sufficient, technically speaking.

**Licensing:**

A) If you're an individual developer (no enterprise, no organization), no difference (AFAIK), you can use CommunityEdition like you'd use the paid edition (as long as you don't do subcontracting)
B) You can use CommunityEdition freely for OpenSource (OSI) projects
C) If you're an educational insitution, you can use CommunityEdition freely (for education/classroom use)
D) If you're an enterprise with 250 PCs or users or  more than one million US dollars in revenue (including subsidiaries), you are **NOT ALLOWED** to use CommunityEdition. 
E) If you're not an enterprise as defined above, and don't do OSI or education, but are an "enterprise"/organization, with **5 or less concurrent (VS) developer**s, you can use VS Community freely (but only if you're the owner of the software and sell it, **not if you're a subcontractor** creating software **for** a larger enterprise, software which in the end the enterprise will *own*), **otherwise you need a paid edition.**

The above does not consitute legal advise. 
See also:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262916/understanding-visual-studio-community-edition-license

Comment: so it has these right? "On the other hand, syntax highlighting, IntelliSense, Step-Through debugging, GoTo-Definition, Git-Integration and Build/Publish are really all the features I need, and I guess that applies to a lot of developers."

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Yep, it has all these.

Comment: @StefanSteiger just to be sure, so if I'm a solo developer and sell some software developer with Visual Studio Community and in turn gain over 1 million in revenue (or any amount), I still don't need a paid license?

Comment: @Vallentin: My interpretation of the license is, that "the second" you cross the 1 million line, you need to stop developing in VS, or aquire a license. However, I don't think those 10k should be a problem if you really make 10E6 in revenue. Otherwise you can use SharpDevelop, Eclipse or MonoDevelop. If you really want to be sure, ask Microsoft by email, and store the response on paper. Even safer, ask by registered mail.

Comment: @StefanSteiger of course, in the grand scheme of things, 10K is nothing compared to 1M. Also is the license only needed for use of VS, what about just using their MSVC compiler? As if it's only VS you need a license for, then in a sense, never mentioning publicly that you use VS, they'd never really know (purely hypothetical speaking, as a question).

Comment: @Vallentin: No that would be a mistake. Microsoft can look into your network, especially if you run Windows server. But they can also get that info via Windows-Update. Since Visual Studio only runs on Windows, there's little chance they won't realize. Theoretically you could use a VM in VirtualBox/vmWare, and run Visual Studio there with completely no network connection. But that just is too goddamn slow. And you can't do it for web-services, etc.

Comment: @Vallentin: But yes, if you make a makefile and only use the compiler, then yes. The csharp compiler does ship with the .NET framework, AFAIK. However, I'd wonder how you would debug such a thing. With logging ? And in the end, you really need an IDE, for Intellisense, formatting, goto-definition, search and replace in a project, etc. Also for version-control, though git could do that, when you only have makefiles. Maybe Visual-Studio-Code would be interesting ? Also, JetBrains is bringing a C# IDE (called "Rider") on the market. Maybe have a look at that once it is finished.

Comment: @Vallentin: However, Rider won't be fully free either, but at the very least you can finally shed/dump Windows while keep using C#.

Comment: @StefanSteiger C# aside, did the MSVC compiler need a license as well? I get that Microsoft has "spyware" to figure out if I use Visual Studio. But that's also a bit far fetched. As in if I use Visual Studio for pet projects, but then develop a commercial project on the same computer not using Visual Studio. Then clearly they won't get far with the "You use Visual Studio" argument, because they don't know to what I'm using it for. If they do, then that would probably raise quite a few more red flags and privacy concerns in general.

Comment: @Vallentin: If you only want to use native C/C++ command line compilation, maybe take a look at MinGW/msys. Perhaps CodeBlocks. For C#, look at Roslyn, much better than msvc.

Comment: None of this applies to Visual Studio for Mac: you can do the same thing with Community, Pro or Enterprise. There is not any real diff

Comment: @Diomedes Domínguez: Visual Studio for Mac is actually just rebranded MonoDevelop. On Windows, it's called XamarinStudio. But it's the same thing. And no, MonoDevelop/VisualStudioMac - there is a massive difference to Visual Studio. But for developing MVC/SPA web-applications, it can be used. Try WebForms or WinForms or WPF with VisualStudioMac, you'll see what I mean. MonoDevelop is a nice, usable piece of software with a good license - but if you say it has no real difference to VisualStudio, that's just plain wrong. Visual Studio can do a lot more than .NET/web-development.

Comment: On VS for Mac I can do exactly the same with Community, Professional or Enterprise. I even get TFS suppport. What I need is a complete table with the pros and cons on each edition, MS hasn't release any because right now three are the same.

Comment: @Diomedes Domínguez: There is only one version of MonoDevelop. The source code license is MIT. It makes little sense to make a Community/Professional/Enterprise edition. https://github.com/mono/monodevelop
If you code on a Mac, I'd use JetBrains Rider instead anyway.

Answer (score 37):

Visual Studio Community is same (*almost*) as professional edition. What differs is that VS community do not have TFS features, and the licensing is different. As stated by @Stefan.

The different versions on VS are compared here - 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs

[image]

Comment: Lab Management is the ability to (automatically) setup Virtual Environments that I mentioned.

Comment: I used TFS (Team Foundation Server) with VS community edition 2015. Thus it is possible. But here I see that, there is no available feature for the TFS in VS Studio Community. It's a bit confusing to me. Will you please clarify me about this?

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel - You can use it as TFS client, and you can connect to TFS server, take latest, checkin, checkout etc. But you cannot use it as TFS server. TFS server is a much comprehensive tool. You can read more about it here - https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel: This is correct. You can indeed use it as TFS client. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I can't find any picture like this one for Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 24):

All these answers are partially wrong.

Microsoft has clarified that Community is for **ANY USE** as long as your revenue is under $1 Million US dollars.  That is literally the only difference between Pro and Community.  Corporate or free or not, irrelevant.

Even the lack of TFS support is not true.  I can verify it is present and works perfectly.

EDIT: Here is an MSDN post regarding the $1M limit: [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/325e6588-31f3-4864-97b5-416e5d1fc4f1/which-visual-studio-is-right-for-me?forum=vssetup) (hint: it's in the VS 2017 license)

EDIT: Even over the revenue limit, open source is still free.

Comment: @Chris Bordeman, can you please provide a link where MS says this? I know that is true because on VS for Mac I can do the same regardless the edition, but because you said that MS clarified this, I need a link to prove my boss and save money

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/325e6588-31f3-4864-97b5-416e5d1fc4f1/which-visual-studio-is-right-for-me?forum=vssetup

Comment: There's no support for things thing XLST transformation debugging in community whereas there is in professional....

Comment: Also, If your organization has more than 250 PC's, It is considered as an enterprise irrespective of the revenue.

Comment: I think this answer is a bit outdated now (or was lacking a bit of info the whole time), as the [VS 2022 license](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/vs2022-ga-community/) explicitly states that you must also only have 5 or fewer people using VS to develop for your organization if you're not an enterprise.

Comment: It was outdated pretty quickly.

Comment: There are other differences, for example Community only displays reference counts over classes, methods, and such whereas Professional also the number of changes and authors.