# Visual Studio 2017 Upgrade from Community to Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am a CS student and through my school I got a license to upgrade to enterprise. I have been mainly using Python up to this point, however in the fall semester I will be using C/C++. Would it be of best interest to uninstall the community version and install the enterprise version? Would I be able to take advantage of the features as a student?

If so, should I uninstall the community version first so there is no issues? Or would it be fine to download enterprise and once I get all my Python packages in the enterprise version uninstall the community version?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Starting from Visual Studio 2017, there is no more upgrade. Community and Enterprise editions can install side by side.

So with a valid Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise license, you should download Visual Studio 2017 installer and choose Enterprise edition to move on. You can of course uninstall Community edition if you want to save disk space.

Comment: I  ended up switching over to Visual Studio Enterprise. Just in case someone is interested and wants some reference. I went ahead and installed it while I had the community version installed and so far it has been working just fine. It did however nicknamed the installation as (2). It is not a big deal to me but it might be to someone.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Manny You can choose the nickname. It is on the right side where you can define the installation folder before the actual installation.

Comment: I guess this is also true for the Professional version, is it?

Comment: @MMalke yes it is

Comment: @Revx0r: How can a student afford VS Enterprise? Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: @Kr15 If your school has a software program that has a deal with Microsoft you can get a license through there. I also believe you can get it through Microsoft just by verifying you are a student. To be honest though, you don't really need Enterprise, Community will work just fine as a student and beyond. I hardly ever use it that much anymore; I now use Visual Studio Code mostly which is lightweight, cross platform and “free.”

Comment: Although Visual Studio is still the choice of most big tech companies dealing with C++ and C# Windows UI projects. In my opinion, it is nice when the university/school has this deal with Microsoft instead of teaching just with Visual Studio Code. I work on a company with 1400 projects, and Visual Studio is simply unreplaceable for that. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285135/whats-the-difference-between-visual-studio-community-and-other-paid-versions/37983606) out for differences among visual studio versions.