# About Vs2019 community or professional or enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I want to install visual studio 2019. So i want to know what s the difference between community/professional/enterprise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between Visual Studio Community and other, paid versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285135/whats-the-difference-between-visual-studio-community-and-other-paid-versions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the only difference between the Community and Professional editions of Visual Studio is one of licensing. There is no operational difference between the two editions.

Visual Studio Enterprise is the most feature-rich and most expensive. It is aimed primarily at software architects and QA experts. In this case, Visual Studio Enterprise might make sense, as long as you have plenty of budget.  But if you don’t, a lot of plugins in the Visual Studio ecosystem can help you get VS Enterprise’s features (https://www.ndepend.com/features/dependency-graph-matrix-architecture).

Answer (score 1):

One difference is that for e.g. Visual 2019 Professional you can go back to former versions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release) which is not possible for the Community Edition.